# How to disable authorization for a request having particular headers in spring boot security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Currently I have a spring boot app that uses oauth2 authorization and validates a request with token against the jwt resource server.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt());
    }
}
```

How can i disable this authorization for a request having particular headers? For example if a request comes with a header as "internal-key", I want to disable jwt authorization for such requests and allow that request.

Comment: Do you want to skip authentication as a whole, or just the authorization part?

Comment: Authentication is not done by the backend service. We have an app that authenticates the user and for every backend call passes the authorization bearer token and the backend validates the token for authorization. So I want to just skip the authorization here.